# Configuration for windows server is missing

Tags: snmpd

SNMPFWD is discussion forum is hosted on stack overflow and object items discussed can not be found.  In trying to implement a windows based portion of the package no code links are available.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like SNMPFWD is a Python library. It can be installed by running `pip install snmpfwd` on a command line.

You'll need to have Python installed on your windows system to do so. You can download the latest Python release for Windows here: https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/